# -128 as binary literal in Java

Tags: java

Based on the fact that a `byte` type in java is a signed 8 bit  [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) integer, why doesn't the second way of declaring a byte work?

```
byte ok = -128;
byte notok = 0b10000000;
```

My understanding is that `1000000` should be `-128` but java indicates the `notok` variable above should be an `int` and not a `byte`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`0b10000000` is an `int` literal (`= 0b00000000000000000000000010000000`) which equals to `+128`. `byte` holds 8 bits and cannot represent `+128`. However, you can achieve this as follows:

```
byte notok = (byte) 0b10000000;
```

Comment: Did you mean byte holds 8 bits?

Comment: @Uli Yes. Corrected :)

Comment: By definition in two's complement, 1000 0000 equals -128.

Comment: @imrichardcole the literal `0b10000000` represents an `int`, not `byte`. That's why.

Comment: i might add to this that the assignment of the int literal only works due to implicite casting, that might clear it up a bit more.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, as mentioned by `Eng Fouad`, ***0b10000000*** is an integer literal. Integer literals create an int value, the size of which in Java is  32-bit.The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer.

So assigning the integer literal to a byte type would not work. To create a conversion between two incompatible types, one must use a cast.

```
 b = (byte)0b10000000;        // (This is narrowing conversion)
```

---

<sub>Also, the signed 2's complement representation of `-128` is [`110000000`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=a61f5ebd0b65d21b82d6a49bab91ecef). But, the MSB 's 1 can be discarded(represents negative sign bit) and hence ***10000000*** is acceptable as 2's complement representation of -128.</sub>